# key too large to index for couting the frequence by aggregating

Tags: mongodb

I tried to use aggregate to calculate the frequnce of the documents having the same `normalized_link`

It gives me the `key too large to index` and seems the value of normalized_link `\"http://www.funpepper.com/share/game/?infos=OtnZDeyCWe5oR-ziY_-p...\"` is too long.

However, the value `\"http://www.funpepper.com/share/game/?infos=OtnZDeyCWe5oR-ziY_-p...\"` is what I want to count

How could I do it? thanks

## Error message

```
    {
      "errmsg": "exception: insert for $out failed: { connectionId: 1, err: \"Btree::insert: key too large to index, failing alibuddha.tmp.agg_out.2.$_id_ 1208 { : \"http://www.funpepper.com/share/game/?infos=OtnZDeyCWe5oR-ziY_-p...\", code: 17280, n: 0, ok: 1.0 }",
```

## query syntax

```
      pipeline = [
        {
        '$project': {
          'doc': '$$ROOT',
          'id': '$$ROOT.ID',
          'normalized_link': '$$ROOT.normalized_link'
            }
        },
        { "$group": {
            "_id": "$doc.normalized_link",
            "frequency": { "$sum": 1 }
        }},
        {
            '$project': {
              'count': '$count',
            }
          }, {
            '$out': "stats_records"
          }
    ]



    db["comments"].runCommand('aggregate', {
      pipeline: pipeline,
      allowDiskUse: true
    });
```

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to do here. 1. You seem to misunderstand `$$ROOT` and that whole intial `$project` stage could be removed. 2. If anything you are trying to count occurances of distinct "normalized_link", and that is pretty much the only stage needed here, but possibly causing problems as `_id` ( a mandatory index ) on disk, so therefore just name the field something else before proceeding to `$out`. 3. Your next `$project` references `$count`, which is a field that does not exist since it was not specified in the `$group`. Note if you remove `_id` then `$out` will generate one.